# Querying XML file with OPENXML in SQL in the process of storing XML data to SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, openxml

I am using the IRS -900 tax file
https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/200931393493000150_public.xml
to create a  single table containing all elements, attributes with their associated values using SQL `OPENXML`. I have built the query just to see if I can get few result as shown below. But I only get an empty table.

I also tried to use online utility to create `xpath` reference or the XML tree of the document to identify the elements and attributes in this long XML file.

Please suggest any easy tool to list all elements and attributes easily as I think the `xpath` reference is the issue.

Here is my code

--created a table for the xml document inside sql server
--Example XML: https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/200931393493000150_public.xml

```
USE [IRS-900]
GO

CREATE TABLE [200931393493000150_public] (
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,XMLData XML
    ,LoadedDateTime DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO [200931393493000150_public] (
    XMLData
    ,LoadedDateTime
    )
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn
    ,GETDATE()
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\200931393493000150_public.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

--select * from [dbo].[200931393493000150_public]
DECLARE @x XML -- to load the binary file to a readable xml document in sql 

SELECT @x = p
FROM
    -- to load the document I used openrowset
    openrowset(BULK 'C:\Users\200931393493000150_public.xml', single_blob) AS [200931393493000150_public](p)

DECLARE @hdoc INT -- out put parameter 

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT
    ,@x

SELECT *
--into table x - will load the result into sql table on the fly 
-- xpath to the element , 1 is for attributes and 2 for elements 
--from  openxml(@hdoc, '//*',1)
--from  openxml(@hdoc, '/root//*',1)
--from  openxml(@hdoc, '/root//*',1)
--with specifies columns to be retreived
FROM openxml(@hdoc, '/root/returnheader/Filer/USAddress', 2)
    -- flag 1 for attributes 
    -- flag 2 for elements 
    WITH (
        EIN CHAR(10) '/../../@EIN'
        ,-- to refer the xpath for the attribute 
        AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50)
        ,AddressLine2 INT
        ,City VARCHAR(50)
        ,STATE VARCHAR(50)
        ,ZIPCode CHAR(5)
        )

--catch release 
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO

-- I have got empty table with the corresponding 6 columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument`  and `sp_xml_removedocument` are mostly kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL Server 2000.

Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards it is better to use XQuery methods `.nodes()` and .`value()` to achieve what you need.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @targetTable TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  
    EIN CHAR(10), 
    AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50),
    AddressLine2 VARCHAR(50),
    City VARCHAR(50),
    State CHAR(2),
    ZIPCode CHAR(5)
);

-- directly from the XML file as a virtual DB table on the file system
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.irs.gov/efile')
, rs (xmldata) AS
(
   SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) AS BulkColumn 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\200931393493000150_public.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
INSERT INTO @targetTable
SELECT c.value('(EIN/text())[1]', 'CHAR(10)') AS EIN
   , c.value('(USAddress/AddressLine1/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS AddressLine1
   , c.value('(USAddress/AddressLine2/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS AddressLine2
   , c.value('(USAddress/City/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS City
   , c.value('(USAddress/State/text())[1]','CHAR(2)') AS State
   , c.value('(USAddress/ZIPCode/text())[1]','CHAR(5)') AS ZIPCode
FROM rs AS tbl
   CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/Return/ReturnHeader/Filer') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @targetTable;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------+
| ID |    EIN     |            AddressLine1             | AddressLine2 |    City    | State | ZIPCode |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------+
|  1 | 541599550  | c/o Piascik Assoc PC 4470 Cox Rd No |          250 | Glen Allen | VA    |   23060 |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much this proves the test. my end goal is to query the entire attributes , and elements to a single table. I will continue down this  path to get the result. As the xml document is really big is there a simple tool to list attributes and elements from the document ? Thanks again

Comment: "...As the xml document is really big is there a simple tool to list attributes and elements from the document ?..." Oxygen XML IDE comes to mind.

Comment: @Divola, I downloaded your 2nd XM file. I compared both files. They are identical.  Please make sure that you are sharing a correct link for the 2nd XML file.

Comment: what is the reason we used DEFAULT 'http://www.irs.gov/efile. thanks

Comment: @Divola, because your original XML had a default namespace `<Return xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile"...`

Comment: @Divola, without a default namespace, it should start as follows: `;WITH rs (xmldata)...`

Comment: Thank you very much. well noted

Comment: @Divola, good to hear that the proposed answer is working for you. Please connect with me on LinkedIn.